# asp.net unchecked checkbox pass not value as NULL

Tags: c#, asp.net, checkbox

I'am trying to insert some data from ASP.NET  DropDownList and CheckBox to database
if the Checkbox is checked I want to insert DropDownList value
if not checked I want to pass null. But in my table it inserts 0 not NULL
How can I pass null instead of zero (0) if it is not checked?
Her is my code:

```
if (CheckBoxMorning.Checked == true)
   {
     SqlParameter paramMorning = new SqlParameter("@Morning", DropDownMorning.SelectedValue);
     cmd.Parameters.Add(paramMorning);
    }

     else
    {
      SqlParameter paramMorning = new SqlParameter("@Morning", CheckBoxMorning.Checked);
      cmd.Parameters.Add(paramMorning);
     }
```

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your current code is inserting `0` in database because `CheckBoxMorning.Checked` is a boolean which evaluates to 0 & 1. You will have to pass `DBNull.Value` in the *SqlParameter* method like this:-

```
SqlParameter paramMorning = new SqlParameter("@Morning", DBNull.Value);
```

Answer (score 1):

Adding to @Rahul 's anwer,your code could be made shorter and easy to understand by doing like:

```
  SqlParameter paramMorning = new SqlParameter("@Morning", CheckBoxMorning.Checked ? DropDownMorning.SelectedValue : DBNull.Value);
  cmd.Parameters.Add(paramMorning);
```

Answer (score 0):

CheckBoxMorning.Checked is always going to have a non-NULL value.

If you want to reinterpret not-checked-ness as NULL, you'll need another IF-like structure and assign DBNull.value in cases where Checked is false.